# Change opengl object vertices in Android onCameraFrme

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am making an application with Opengl and Opencv.
Opencv identifies the corners of a square on the screen.
I apply an algorithm that converts the screen coordinates of points into Cartesian coordinates into opengl, and I create the vertices.
But each point taken from the four caught in the square is modified to each frame,
so the float array of vertices also changes with each frame, how to change the vertices to each frame?

**this is MyGLSurfaceView**

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

    Context context;
    Model3D model3D;

    float[] vertices;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, float[] vertices){
       this.context = context;
       this.vertices = vertices;
       //ColocaModel(gl,vertices);
       model3D = new Model3D(vertices);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        model3D.model3DTexture(gl,context);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  // Enable texture (NEW)
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (height == 0) height = 1;   // To prevent divide by zero
        float aspect = (float)width / height;

        // Set the viewport (display area) to cover the entire window
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        // Setup perspective projection, with aspect ratio matches viewport
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select projection matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset projection matrix
        // Use perspective projection
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, aspect, 0.1f, 100.f);


        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);  // Select model-view matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
        //gl.glTranslatex(200, 500, -6);
        //gl.glRotatef(angleCube, 0.1f, 1.0f, 0.2f);
        model3D = new Model3D(vertices);
        model3D.draw(gl,vertices);
    }
}
```

**My object**

```
public class Model3D {


    float[] texCoords = { // Texture coords for the above face (NEW)
            0.0f, 1.0f,  // A. left-bottom (NEW)
            1.0f, 1.0f,  // B. right-bottom (NEW)
            0.0f, 0.0f,  // C. left-top (NEW)
            1.0f, 0.0f   // D. right-top (NEW)
    };

    int[] textureIDs = new int[1]; //array para 1 textura

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer texBuffer;

    public Model3D(float[] vertices){
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4);
        tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
        texBuffer.put(texCoords);
        texBuffer.position(0);
    }
    public void model3DTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]);   // Bind to texture ID
        // Set up texture filters
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        // Construct an input stream to texture image "res\drawable\nehe.png"
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image2);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            // Read and decode input as bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream);
        } finally {
            try {
                istream.close();
            } catch(IOException e) { }
        }

        // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture ID
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl,float[] vertices){
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  // Enable texture-coords-array (NEW)
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define texture-coords buffer (NEW)

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0,vertexBuffer);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,vertices.length/3);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

**My call**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyGLSurfaceView view = new MyGLSurfaceView(this,vertices);

        glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glView);
        glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        glView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        glView.setRenderer(view);

        glView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);


At this point is where I would like to make the vertex change


    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

...
...


These are my converted vertices 

    public float[] vertices = {
            xCP4, yCP4, 0.0f,
            xCP3, yCP3, 0.0f,
            xCP1, yCP1, 0.0f,
            xCP2, yCP2, 0.0f
    };
```

Comment: The `vertexBuffer` must be refilled at the first command of your `draw` function.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: `vertexBuffer.put(vertices)` is used, but only during `Model3D` initialization. You should add a public function to this class for this job.

Comment: Please, can you show me an example? I could not implement your idea.